# how to re-run only failed tests in the bamboo?

Tags: ant, selenium, testng, bamboo

We are running our tests o bamboo. But if any test failed on bamboo we have to run the bamboo again with the all tests. Is there any way with which we can run only failed tests on bamboo. Is there is a need to change in our framework means any help in ant build.xml file or testNG file as we are using java+Ant+TestNG for our test cases to execute. Or is there is any thing in bamboo that help us ?????

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that Bamboo can solve this problem for you.  It sounds like you need a way to identify the failing builds, and then trigger them again.  Most likely you'd need this in a separate plan in bamboo.  The details would have to be handled in your test calling framework most likely.

Comment: Thanks for info. But we solved the issue by creating testng reporter class.